# Best (fastest) way to find the number most frequently entered in C?

Tags: c, optimization

Well, I think the title basically explains my doubt. I will have **n** numbers to read, this **n** numbers go from **1** to **x**, where x is at most 10<sup>5</sup>. What is the **fastest** (less possible time to run it) way to find out which number were inserted more times? That **knowing that the number that appears most times appears more than half of the times**.

What I've tried so far:

```
//for (1<=x<=10⁵)
int v[100000+1];

//multiple instances , ends when n = 0
while (scanf("%d", &n)&&n>0) {
    zerofill(v);
    for (i=0; i<n; i++) {
        scanf("%d", &x);
        v[x]++;
        if (v[x]>n/2)
            i=n;
    }
    printf("%d\n", x);
}
```

Zero-filling a array of **x** positions and increasing the position vector[x] and at the same time verifying if vector[x] is greater than n/2 it's **not** fast enough.

Any idea might help, thank you.

*Observation: No need to care about amount of memory used.*

Comment: vector would imply C++, not C... you'd probably need to retag your question to get the answer you need. Adding code, showing what you've tried so far is required, too

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem Sorry, I meant array not vector, an array is a "vetor" in my native language.

Comment: How are you measuring "fastest?" By "least code?" By "wall-clock fastest, even if it means hand-coding it in assembly?"

Comment: @templatetypedef by fastest I mean in the way it runs in less time, sorry for not pointing that out.

Comment: insert all into a priority queue and later pop the first element, This should be the one inserted the most times

Comment: The elephant in the room is that `scanf` is going to take more CPU than the rest of the algorithm. If you are worried about run time, then you need to optimize the IO, not the algorithm.

Comment: I updated your question with information about the upper bound on the size of the numbers. That's actually pretty important for deciding how to solve this problem!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The trivial solution of keeping a counter array is `O(n)` and you obviously can't get better than that. The fight is then about the constants and this is where a lot of details will play the game, including exactly what are the values of `n` and `x`, what kind of processor, what kind of architecture and so on.

On the other side this seems really the "knockout" problem, but that algorithm will need two passes over the data and an extra conditional, thus in practical terms in the computers I know it will be most probably slower than the array of counters solutions for a lot of `n` and `x` values.

The good point of the knockout solution is that you don't need to put a limit `x` on the values and you don't need any extra memory.

If you know already that there is a value with the absolute majority (and you simply need to find what is this value) then this could make it (but there are two conditionals in the inner loop):

- initialize `count = 0`
- loop over all elements
- if `count` is `0` then set `champion = element` and `count = 1`
- else if `element != champion` decrement `count`
- else increment `count`

at the end of the loop your `champion` will be the value with the absolute majority of elements, if such a value is present.

But as said before I'd expect a trivial

```
for (int i=0,n=size; i<n; i++) {
    if (++count[x[i]] > half) return x[i];
}
```

to be faster.

### EDIT

After your edit seems you're really looking for the knockout algorithm, but caring about speed that's probably still the wrong question with modern computers (100000 elements is nothing even for a nail-sized single chip today).

Comment: Yes, I do know for certain that one value will have the absolute majority. Your solution seems brilliant, I would never have thought of that. Will try it now, thank you!

Comment: I had a need to care about speed in order to be able to solve the problem in a given time, running in a specific ambient, this exercise is part of a college work. Your idea of the counter was faster enough than my array algorithm, it will work for my needs, thank you very much. Now thinking about absolute speed, would you be able to point out the fastest (a candidate) way/algorithm to solve this kind of problems? (not necessarily related to C), I really like this optimizing stuff, learning Assembly is one of my next goals.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can create a max heap for the count of number you read,and use heap sort to find all the count which greater than n/2

Comment: Don't know if I'm stating the obvious but it will be only one entering wich appears more then n/2 times. Also, I don't think I've quite followed your logic, sorry.

Comment: This is also the approach I would use. I've suggested using std::priority_queue from stl library

Comment: about `maximum heap`,you can reference here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Min-max_heap

Comment: Thank you, solved my problem already but will take a look on that.